# Question on comparing two probability spaces

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, negative-binomial

Let's assume we have two discrete probability spaces $(\Omega_1,P_1)$ which describes experiment $1$ and $(\Omega_2,P_2)$ which describes experiment $2$. We know the probability $P_1$ but we don't know exactly how $P_2$ looks like. For a set $A\subset \Omega_2$ we know that $P_2(A)=\frac{1}{3}$. Now we find out that $A\subset \Omega_1$ and that for all $\omega\in A$ experiment $2$ is the same as experiment $1$.

E.g. experiment $1$ is a negative binomial experiment and all $\omega\in A$ also satisfy the conditions of the negative binomial experiment.

Does this imply $P_1(A)=P_2(A)=\frac{1}{3}$ or $P_1(\omega)=P_2(\omega)$, $\forall \omega\in A$? If yes, why? If not, why?

Comment: What does "experiment 2 is the same as experiment 1" mean? Do you have an example of this situation?

Comment: @Karl, I have edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.